# Get link and title of sub link in a homepage

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to get a link inside the homepage of the website,
I tried to get it by selenium but only get the homepage link.
please help me to get all links inside.

Code trials:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('https://m.cafe.naver.com/ca-fe/minivelobike')

time.sleep(7)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
driver.close()
```

Snapshot of the links:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the *`href`* attributes of the articles you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://m.cafe.naver.com/ca-fe/minivelobike")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.txt_area[href]")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://m.cafe.naver.com/ca-fe/minivelobike")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='txt_area' and @href]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074719&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074718&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074717&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074716&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074715&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074714&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074713&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074712&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074711&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074710&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074709&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074708&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074707&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074704&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074703&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074702&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074701&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074700&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074699&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074698&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074697&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074696&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074695&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074694&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074693&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074692&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074691&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074690&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074689&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074688&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074687&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074686&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074685&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074682&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074681&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074680&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074679&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074678&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074677&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074676&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074675&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074674&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074673&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074672&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074671&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074670&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074669&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074668&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074667&boardtype=L', 'https://m.cafe.naver.com/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=11853711&articleid=1074666&boardtype=L']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks you! It worked. I'm trying to add "tit" on <Strong data, and combine URL and 'tit' to send by BOT. Please help me update the code.

Comment: Sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('https://m.cafe.naver.com/ca-fe/minivelobike')
time.sleep(7)
wrapper = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ct")
main_ul = wrapper.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "ul")
for li in main_ul.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li"):
    try:
        anchor_tag = li.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
        href = anchor_tag.get_attribute("href")
        print(href)
    except:
        print("Anchor tag doesnt exist")
```